# Rails Versioning in a single table, but without serialization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, version

I haven't found a gem that does this, but I would like a way to keep my records and their previous versions, all as columns in the same table.  I don't want to have duplicates like a Widgets table and a WidgetVersions table like paper_trail, nor do I want a serialized version of my object in a blob in one column.  I need everything stored in the database so another IT group can read the previous versions from the database efficiently with no extra processing.

Does anyone know of a gem that works this way, or do I have to roll my own?

Answer (score -1):

The simplest way is add two columns to table: revision_id and revision_time.

On update you simply create a new record with revision_id + 1 and revision_time = current time

Comment: What about records ids and associations?

Comment: the author of the question did not mention anything about associations as in such case it should be handled in the object being updated not the parent object

Comment: Yes you are right, he did not mentioned it. However if you know Rails a little bit you should realize how much your suggestion would break the fundamentals of Rails. I give you just one example to keep my comment short: after saving your controller redirect to the view page which is based on the record ID. Did you mention that he would have to hack that?  You suggestion would make problems worse, that's why I down-voted it to indicate to other that its not to be followed. Thank you